# Why is my twig variable not working inside my block twig?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a field I'm pulling into a block twig template `block--block-03.html.twig`, and it outputs fine by itself (= `{{content.field_content_side}}`). But when I put it inside of a conditional it is not working.

Here's my code to illustrate what I mean:

```
<h1>{{ content.field_content_side }}</h1>
<h2>{% if content.field_content_side == 'left' %}col-sm-push-7{% else %}wtf{% endif %}</h2>
```

The output is here:

[image]

Why is it recognizing the twig variable correctly as `left` (= 1st line of my code), but in the conditional it is saying it's not `left` (= 2nd line of my code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the field is being rendered, which is different than evaluating its value. `content.field_content_side` is a render array which holds a lot more than just 'value'.

Try:

```
{% if node.field_content_side.value == 'left' %}
```

To get this in a block, you would add this to `mytheme.theme`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_block().
 * @param $variables
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'])) {
    $variables['block_content'] = $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'];
  }
}
```

Then:

```
{% if block_content.field_content_side.value == 'left' %}
```

Comment: I updated the question above to indicate its inside of a block twig template, not a node. I tried `content.field_content_side.value` which did not work either.

Comment: Then you need to add it in. I will update the answer.

Comment: `content.field_content_side.value` is never going to work from a render array.

Comment: you are a life saver. I dont entirely understand what the preprocess function is doing here, but it works and has saved me lots of time. Thank you!

Comment: It is basically appending the field data in to the block so it is available in the template, similar to having access to the node object in a node template hence the initial `if node.field_content_side.value == 'left'`. So `block_content` is the block object and fields. Render arrays can't be used that way, and its one of the things many people run into when trying to do something like this.